# Case "Internal Comments" in VisualforcePage and Controller

Tags: visualforce, class

Below is my Apex Page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Process_Adherence_Monitoring__c" extensions="PAM_QuestionButtonPageController">

<apex:form >
<apex:pageMessages id="msg"/>
 <!-- Case Section  --> 
   <apex:pageBlock title="New Case">
    <apex:pageBlockButtons >
     <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Save"/>
     <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!Cancel}"/>
    </apex:pageBlockButtons>
 <apex:pageBlockSection title="Case Information"  collapsible="false"> 
   <apex:repeat value="{!ccLIst}" var="cc"> 
     <apex:outputfield label="Organization Name" value="{!cc.Accountid}"/>
     <apex:inputfield value="{!cc.Contactid}"/>
     <apex:inputfield value="{!cc.Status}"/>
     <apex:inputfield value="{!cc.Invalid_Request__c}"/>
     <apex:outputfield value="{!cc.Reason}"/> 
     <apex:inputfield value="{!cc.Invalid_FTR__c}"/>
     <apex:outputfield value="{!cc.Subcategories__c}"/>
     <apex:inputfield value="{!cc.Invalid_Detail__c}"/>
     <apex:inputfield value="{!cc.Priority}"/>
     <apex:inputfield value="{!cc.Turn_Off_Auto_response__c}"/>
     <apex:inputfield value="{!cc.Privileged__c}"/>
     <apex:inputfield value="{!cc.Bus_Dev__c}"/>
     <apex:inputfield value="{!cc.Origin}"/>
     <apex:inputfield value="{!cc.Type}"/>
     <apex:inputfield value="{!cc.OwnerId}"/>
     <apex:inputfield value="{!cc.ParentId}"/>
   </apex:repeat>
  </apex:pageBlockSection> 
 <apex:pageBlockSection title="Case Outcome"  columns="1"> 
    <apex:repeat value="{!ccLIst}" var="cc"> 
     <apex:inputfield value="{!cc.Outcome_FTR__c}"/>  
     <apex:inputfield value="{!cc.Outcome_Description__c}"/>
    </apex:repeat> 
 </apex:pageBlockSection>  
  <apex:pageBlockSection title="Case Details"  columns="1"> 
    <apex:repeat value="{!ccLIst}" var="cc"> 
     <apex:inputfield label="Question Short Description" value="{!cc.Subject}"/>
     <apex:inputfield label="Question Details" value="{!cc.Description}"/>
    </apex:repeat> 
 </apex:pageBlockSection>  
  <apex:pageBlockSection title="System Information"  columns="1" collapsible = "false"> 
    <apex:repeat value="{!ccLIst}" var="cc"> 
     <apex:outputfield value="{!cc.Process_Adherence_Monitoring__c}"/>
     <apex:outputfield value="{!cc.RecordTypeId}"/>
    </apex:repeat> 
 </apex:pageBlockSection>  
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Below is my Apex Class:

```
public with sharing class PAM_QuestionButtonPageController {

    List<Case> CaseList = new List<Case>();
    List<Case> CasetoDisplay = new List<Case>();
    public boolean showCase{get;set;}


    public PAM_QuestionButtonPageController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
         Map<String,Schema.RecordTypeInfo> rtMap = Schema.SObjectType.Case.getRecordTypeInfosByName();
         Id rtLeadID =  rtMap.get('Operations - PAM').getRecordTypeId(); 
        Id pageId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
        Process_Adherence_Monitoring__c[] PAMList = [select id,Account_Number__c,Organization_Name__c  from Process_Adherence_Monitoring__c where id =: pageId];

        String sCase = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('showCC');
        system.debug('sCase-->'+sCase);
        if(sCase == '1')
        {
            showCase = true;
            system.debug('showCase-->>'+showCase);
        }

        CaseList = [Select id,Reason,Subcategories__c,Accountid,OwnerId,RecordTypeId FROM Case WHERE Process_Adherence_Monitoring__c =: pageId limit 1];

        if(CaseList.size() == 0 || CaseList.size() > 0)
        {
        Case c = new Case();
        c.AccountId  = PAMList[0].Organization_Name__c;
        c.Reason = 'Process Adherence Monitoring (PAM)';
        c.Subcategories__c = 'FRB';
        c.RecordTypeId = rtLeadID;
        c.Process_Adherence_Monitoring__c = PAMList[0].Id;
        CasetoDisplay.add(c);
        }
     }
   public list<Case> getccLIst(){
       if(CasetoDisplay.size() >0){
         return CasetoDisplay;
       }
       return null;
   }
   public PageReference save()
   {         
      try{
           if(CasetoDisplay.size() <> null){
             insert CasetoDisplay;
             return new PageReference('/'+CasetoDisplay[0].id);
           }

       }
       catch(Exception ex){
          ApexPages.addMessages(ex);
       }
          return null;

   }   
}
```

I am opening custom case layout from a button on Process Adherence Monitoring object but I am not able to refer Case "Internal Comments" field because I cannot see it in the schema of Case Objects.How do I refer the Internal Comments field in the VisualForce Page?

Answer (score 1):

**Internal Comments** is not really a field, however, it looks like a field on case standard layout. The information entered in this field is actually stored in the CaseComment object which is related to the case.

What I would suggest is that, you put the field as a Large Text Area on your VF, and then handle the data in your Apex controller and insert the record in CaseComment object right after inserting/updating your case data, because that will give you the ID of case record to be used while inserting case comment record.